# Split down the following command

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper

java -cp zookeeper.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:conf \ org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain zoo.cfg

I am trying to understand the above command.All I understood is -cp is followed a list of jar files separated by :. But can any one explain from conf part.Is conf a keyword ?

Answer (score 1):

`java -cp zookeeper.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:conf \ org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain zoo.cfg`

`java` - the java executeable

`-cp zookeeper.jar:lib/log4j-1.2.15.jar:conf` - items to put on the application's classpath

`org.apache.zookeeper.server.quorum.QuorumPeerMain` - the class containing a main method that acts as the entry point to the application

`zoo.cfg` - the configuration file that the QuorumPeerMain class is expected to have passed to it as it's first parameter

`conf` is **not** a keyword, it's just an item that you are adding to the claspath

Comment: what is the \ after conf ?

Comment: and conf might be a folder too ?

Comment: Looks to me like it's a line continuation character, allowing you to split one command on to more than one line either in a script or at the operating system prompt. http://www.dba-oracle.com/op_unix_8_partition_commands_wrapping.htm

Comment: I don't think conf can be a directory unless you have written a customer classloader that will navigate in to any directories that you specify in -cp. Not sure about that though. If you take it out of the class path, does the app still work?

Comment: Nopes.Its actually to run zookeeper.You can download Zookeeper package and see the folder structure.Conf is a folder which has some .cfg files like in this case zoo.cfg.

Comment: Looks like you can add directories to the classpath - I guess they are doing this so that they can get the config file using `getResourceAsStream` in their code.

Comment: Even I think so..Thanks for your help.. :)